# Loop Macro to concatenate cell values

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula

I was wondering if someone could assist. Im trying to create a macro that should run if cell in column D(starting in Cell D14) is not empty.

If cell D14 is not empty then, it should concatenate the value of Cell J, " - ", D$6$, " - " , D. (J and D values should be in Row 14 and then 15 and so on, until there is an empty cell in column D). The result of the concatenation should go in Column K14.

I have added an image of a portion of the excel sheet. Value in D6 should be fixed since its the customer company name.

[image]

Comment: If you are trying to create a macro, then why not include what you have so far?

Comment: With Office 365, you probably can achieve it with native functions. Have you considered? Snapshot is not conclusive to know which columns / data is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this, using a "simple" Excel formula, like this one:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D14))," - " & $D$6 & " - " & D14)
```

The result looks as follows (I've hidden some rows and columns for visibility reasons), and I believe you have made a typo while describing `$D$6` (you wrote `D$6$`).

Screenshot of the solution:

[image]